# Find the longest sequence of same characters in a string

Tags: java

This code supposed to output the longest run on which a character in a string has a consecutive runs of itself. Though the problem is that it outputs: *8* (which should be *5* instead). I just would like to ask what seems to be the problem regarding this code.

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String setofletters = "aaakkcccccczz"; /* 15 */
        int output = runLongestIndex(setofletters);
        System.out.println("Longest run that first appeared in index:" + output);
    }

    public static int runLongestIndex(String setofletters) {
        int ctr = 0;
        int ctrstor = 0;
        int ii = 0;
        int output = 0;

        // loops until the last character in the string
        for (int i = 0; i < setofletters.length() - 1; i++) {
            // checks if the letter is the same to the next
            if (setofletters.charAt(i) == setofletters.charAt(i++)) {
                ctr++;
                ii = i++;
                // loops until the letter in the index is no longer equal
                while (setofletters.charAt(i) == setofletters.charAt(ii)) {
                    ii++;
                    ctr++;
                }

                if (ctr > ctrstor) {
                    output = i;
                }
                // storing purposes
                ctrstor = ctr;
            }
            // resets the counter
            ctr = 0;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read up on the difference between i++,  ++i, and i+1. You misuse them multiple times

Comment: @BoDidely is this regarding the while loop? as you can see there is a "ii=i++"  before the while loop so it does not mean that it will compare it index on itself but rather on other index.

Comment: @Snail `if(setofletters.charAt(i)==setofletters.charAt(i++)` compares the SAME character, THEN increments `i`

Comment: shouldn't the output be **6**?

Comment: @ Reservoir Sampling thanks (Y)

Comment: @Snail next time onwards, try to give reply to comments on your questions. It will help others to understand your problem clearly.

Comment: @Snail  what's the purpose of the internal loop? Is it really needed?

Comment: @Tom Does this task really required internal loop ?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** Sorry, I misunderstood your question a bit, you need to make the following changes in your code to make it work.(lines with comments)

```
   public static int runLongestIndex(String setofletters){
    int ctr = 1; // every character is repeated at least once, so you should initialize it to 1, not 0
    int ctrstor = 0;
    int ii = 0;
    int output = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < setofletters.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (i < setofletters.length() - 1 && setofletters.charAt(i) == setofletters.charAt(i+1)) { // i++ is not same as i+1
            ctr++;
            ii = i+1; // i++ is not same as i+1
            while (setofletters.charAt(i) == setofletters.charAt(ii)) {
                ii++;
                ctr++;
            }

            if (ctr > ctrstor) {
                output = i;
            }
            ctrstor = ctr;
        }
        ctr = 1; // for the same reason I mentioned above
    }
    return output;
}
```

**EDIT** : the easiest way to write your code is :

```
public static int runLongestIndex(String setofletters){ 
   int ctr = 1;
    int output = 0;
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<setofletters.length()-1;i++){
        j=i;
        while(i <setofletters.length()-1 && setofletters.charAt(i)==setofletters.charAt(i+1)){
            i++;
            ctr++;
        }
        if(ctr>output){
            output=j;
        }
        ctr = 1;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Why are you assigning `i` to output? You should assign `ctr` to `output`.

change

```
   if(ctr>ctrstor){
      output=i;
   }
```

to

```
 if(ctr>ctrstor){
      output=ctr;
 }
```

and also I think you should change

```
 if(setofletters.charAt(i)==setofletters.charAt(i++))
```

to

```
 if(i<setofletters.length()-1 && setofletters.charAt(i)==setofletters.charAt(i+1)){
```

and you should intialize `ctr` to `1` but not `0` because every character is repeated at least once.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it and all the others who helped me through this piece of code, it is now working.

Comment: thanks, i tried using "zzxxxccccxxz" as the string and it answered 4, it should be 5 instead.

Comment: @Snail why should it be 5? `cccc` its 4.

Comment: @ReservoirSampling He wrote *"it is **now** working"*, not *"not"* :P.

Comment: I mean the program is supposed to output the index location of the first letter in the string that has the first consecutive same letters so the first letter is C and its first occurrence is located in index 5 right?

Comment: yeah sorry about assuming that it is now in working condition. XD

Comment: @Tom `1:00 AM` sleepy :/

Comment: @Snail sorry,  I was thinking that you need length, but you could have written your question more clearly. In question you have nowhere mentioned that you need index. (I assumed as length, that's my mistake).

Comment: sorry, I was first trying to figure out on how to find the largest consecutive letters but then I realized that it should output the first letter location instead, sorry.

Comment: @Snail No issues :) I edited my code. It works as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a Scala implementation for that problem.

Here it is the automatic test (in BDD style with ScalaTest)

```scala
import org.scalatest._
class RichStringSpec extends FlatSpec with MustMatchers {
  "A rich string" should "find the longest run of consecutive characters" in {
    import Example._
    "abceedd".longestRun mustBe Set("ee", "dd")
    "aeebceeedd".longestRun mustBe Set("eee")
    "aaaaaaa".longestRun mustBe Set("aaaaaaa")
    "abcdefgh".longestRun mustBe empty
  }
}
```

Following is the imperative style implementation, with nested loops and mutable variables as you would normally choose to do in Java or C++:

```scala
object Example {
  implicit class RichString(string: String) {
    def longestRun: Set[String] = {
      val chunks = mutable.Set.empty[String]
      val ilen = string.length
      var gmax = 0
      for ((ch, curr) <- string.zipWithIndex) {
        val chunk = mutable.ListBuffer(ch)
        var next = curr + 1
        while (next < ilen && string(next) == ch) {
          chunk += string(next)
          next = next + 1
        }
        gmax = chunk.length max gmax
        if (gmax > 1) chunks += chunk.mkString
      }
      chunks.toSet.filter( _.length == gmax )
    }
  }
}
```

Following is a functional-style implementation, hence no variables, no loops but tail recursion with result accumulators and pattern matching to compare each character with the next one (Crazy! Isn't it?):

```scala
object Example {
  implicit class RichString(string: String) {
    def longestRun: Set[String] = {
      def recurse(chars: String, chunk: mutable.ListBuffer[Char], chunks: mutable.Set[String]): Set[String] = {
        chars.toList match {
          case List(x, y, _*) if (x == y) =>
            recurse(
              chars.tail, 
              if (chunk.isEmpty) chunk ++= List(x, y) else chunk += y, 
              chunks
            )
          case Nil =>
            // terminate recursion
            chunks.toSet
          case _ => // x != y
            recurse(
              chars.tail,
              chunk = mutable.ListBuffer(), 
              chunks += chunk.mkString
            )
        }
      }
      val chunks = recurse(string, mutable.ListBuffer(), mutable.Set.empty[String])
      val max = chunks.map(_.length).max
      if (max > 0) chunks.filter( _.length == max ) else Set()
    }
  }
}
```

For example, for the given `"aeebceeedd"` string, both implementations above will build the following set of chunks (repeating characters)

```
Set("ee", "eee", "dd")
```

and they will filter those chunks having the maximum length (resulting `"eee"`).

Comment: It's not often I see a Scala answer to a Java question :) But the code can be simpler, and more efficient. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for any length of string sequence.

```
public class LongestStringSequqnce {

static String myString = "aaaabbbbcccchhhhiiiiibbbbbbbbbccccccc";
static int largestSequence = 0;
static char longestChar = '\0';

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int currentSequence = 1;
    char current = '\0';
    char next = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < myString.length() - 1; i++) {
        current = myString.charAt(i);
        next = myString.charAt(i + 1);

        // If character's are in sequence , increase the counter
        if (current == next) {
            currentSequence += 1;
        } else {
            if (currentSequence > largestSequence) { // When sequence is
                                                     // completed, check if
                                                     // it is longest
                largestSequence = currentSequence;
                longestChar = current;
            }
            currentSequence = 1; // re-initialize counter
        }
    }
    if (currentSequence > largestSequence) { // Check if last string
                                             // sequence is longest
        largestSequence = currentSequence;
        longestChar = current;
    }

    System.out.println("Longest character sequence is of character "
            + longestChar + " and is " + largestSequence + " long");
}

}
```

Source : http://www.5balloons.info/program-java-code-to-find-longest-character-sequence-in-a-random-string/

Answer (score 0):

```
       if(ctr>ctrstor){
            output=i;
        }
        //storing purposes
        ctrstor=ctr;
```

This looks like the problem. So if you find 8 consecutive characters, it will set output to 8, and proceed. The next time thru, it finds 3 consecutive characters, so doesn't set output, but sets ctrstor. Next time thru it finds 4 consecutive characters, and this will set output to 4

Answer (score 0):

There are few traps in the code that your logic felt in:

1. Code incorrectly assumes that there is always next character to compare current one.
   This fails for string like `"a"` or the last character in any string.
2. Code does not store the max count of characters but only the max index (`i`).
   MaxCount is needed to compare the next chars sequence size.
3. Loop `for` and loop `while` repeat the same subset of characters.
4. Also variable name style makes it harder to understand the code.

After correcting above

```
public static int runLongestIndex(String setofletters) {
  int maxCount = 0;
  int maxIndex = 0;

  // loops each character in the string
  for (int i = 0; i < setofletters.length() - 1; ) {
    // new char sequence starts here
    char currChar = setofletters.charAt(i);
    int count = 1;
    int index = i;
    while ( (index < setofletters.length() - 1) &&
            (currChar == setofletters.charAt(++index)) ) {
       count++;
    } 

    if (count > maxCount) {
       maxIndex = i;
       maxCount = count;
    }
    i = index;
  }
  return maxIndex;
}
```

See Java [DEMO](http://ideone.com/tnXyFb)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need an internal loop:

```
public static int runLongestIndex(String setofletters) {
    if (setofletters == null || setofletters.isEmpty()) {
      return -1;
    }
    int cnt = 1;
    char prevC = setofletters.charAt(0);
    int maxCnt = 1;
    //char maxC = prevC;
    int maxRunIdx = 0;
    int curRunIdx = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < setofletters.length(); i++){
      final char c = setofletters.charAt(i);
      if (prevC == c) {
        cnt++;
      } else {
        if (cnt > maxCnt) {
          maxCnt = cnt;
          //maxC = prevC;          
          maxRunIdx = curRunIdx;
        }
        cnt = 1;
        curRunIdx = i;
      }
      prevC = c;
    }
    if (setofletters.charAt(setofletters.length() - 1) == prevC) {
      if (cnt > maxCnt) {
        //maxC = prevC;
        maxCnt = cnt;
        maxRunIdx = curRunIdx;
      }
    }
    return maxRunIdx;
  }
```

and this code:
System.out.println(runLongestIndex("aaakkcccccczz")); 
gives you 
5

Answer (score 0):

This is how a "colleague" of mine is understanding to write readable code in order to solve this problem, even if this is working :)

```
    public static int count (String str) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < str.length()-1 && str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1))
        i ++;

    return ++i;

}
public static int getLongestIndex(String str){
    int output = 0;
    for(int i=0, cnt = 1, counter = 0 ; i<str.length() - 1;i += cnt, cnt = count(str.substring(i)), output = (counter = (cnt > counter ? cnt : counter)) == cnt ? i : output);
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int indexOfLongestRun(String str) {

```
       char[] ar = str.toCharArray();
       int longestRun = 0;
       int lastLongestRun = 0;
       int index = 0;
       for(int i = ar.length-1; i>0; i--){
           if(ar[i] == ar[i-1]){
               longestRun++;
           }else{
               if(longestRun > lastLongestRun){
                   lastLongestRun = longestRun;
                   longestRun = 0;
                   index = i;
               }
           }
       }

       return index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution a bit depends on the additional requirements. Here is the code which returns the FIRST longest sequence of a repeated character int the given string, meaning if you have a second sequence with the same length you never get it out :(. But still, this is a simple and clear solution here, so good news - it works! :)

```
string = 'abbbccddddddddeehhhfffzzzzzzzzdddvyy'

longest_sequence = ''
for i in range(len(string)):
    is_sequence = True
    ch_sequence = ''
    while is_sequence:
        ch_sequence += string[i]
        if i+1 < len(string) and string[i]==string[i+1]:
            i += 1
        else:
            is_sequence = False
    if len(ch_sequence) > len(longest_sequence):
        longest_sequence = ch_sequence
print (longest_sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Paolo Angioletti already provided an answer using Scala, but it's more complicated than it needs to be. The idea is not very different from [Run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). Time complexity `O(n)`.

```
def longestConsecutive(s: String): (Char, Int) = {
  Iterator.iterate(('\u0000', 0, 0)) { case (ch, longestRun, i) =>
    val run = (i until s.length)
      .takeWhile(s(_) == s(i))
      .size

    if (run > longestRun) (s(i), run, i + run)
    else (ch, longestRun, i + run)
  }
    .dropWhile(i => s.isDefinedAt(i._3))
    .take(1)
    .map(x => (x._1, x._2))
    .next()
}
```

Tested with:

```
("s", "ch", "n")
----------------
("", '\u0000', 0),
("a", 'a', 1),
("aabcddbbbea", 'b', 3),
("abcddbbb", 'b', 3),
("cbccca", 'c', 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s="abbcccccbbffffffffff";
    //cin>>s;
    int count=1;
    int maxcount=1;
    int start=0;
    int ps=0;
    
    for (int i=0;i<s.size()-1;i++)
    
    {
        if(s.at(i)==s.at(i+1))
        {
            count +=1;
            maxcount=max(maxcount,count);
        }
        else
        {  
             ps=max(ps,start+count);
            count =1;
            start=i;
        }
    }
   
   for(int i=1;i<=maxcount;i++)
   {
       cout<<s.at(i+ps); 
   }
    
    
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest I can think of and it will print the number of the longest sequenced identical characters in a one line string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        
        int count = 0;
        int curCount = 1;
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() -1; i++) {
            
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1)) {
                curCount++;
                if (curCount > count) {
                    count = curCount;
                }
            }else {
                if (curCount > count) {
                    count = curCount;
                }
                curCount = 1;
            }
        }
                
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```